# Html tag of picture,

Tags: html, vba, parsing

I want to parse the url of picture link from amazon, but since I am new to this, I am not sure about its tagname.

I have a vba code that uses 
Set myLinks = html.getElementsByTagName("img") 
to parse, however, cannot find the picture link.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Code:

```
Sub GetAboutUsLinks2()
'First define all the variables

Dim ie As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim myLinks As Object
Dim myLink As Object
Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim LastRow As Integer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
ie.navigate myURL
ie.Visible = True

While ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

result = ie.document.body.innerHTML
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = result

Set myLinks = html.getElementsByTagName("img").
For Each myLink In myLinks
If Right$(myLink, 4) = ".jpg" Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = myLinks
Else
Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Not found"
End If

Next myLink

If i = LastRow Then
ie.Quit
End If
Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: Links have a tagname of "a"

Comment: It would help to show an example of the HTML you're trying to parse, or a sample URL with a description of which part of the page you're trying to capture.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0098C4JKS I want to get the product picture's link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.  There's no need to take the HTML from IE in order to do any parsing: you can work directly with the loaded page.

```
Sub GetAboutUsLinks2()
'First define all the variables

Dim ie As Object
Dim myPic As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ie.navigate myURL

        While ie.busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set myPic = ie.document.getElementById("landingImage")
        If Not myPic Is Nothing Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = myPic.src
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Not found"
        End If

    Next i

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```